# ms access - auto-complete not working on ComboBox

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a ComboBox that has a row source of

```
SELECT tblTCOAppCodes.id, 
       tblTCOAppCodes.tcoAppCode & " : " & tblTCOAppCodes.description AS Description 
FROM tblTCOAppCodes 
ORDER BY tblTCOAppCodes.tcoAppCode;
```

Normally a combo-box allows auto-complete but in this case it does not and I'm assuming it's because I'm concatenating the values from 2 columns.

Screenshot of how the column looks.

[image: ComboBox visual]

Comment: Has the first column (id) a width of 0? Can you add a screenshot of the opened combobox?

Comment: yes.  first column is 0.  specifically the Column Widths are `0";1"` screenshot incoming.

Comment: Try to add new combo box with or without the wizard and configure it as the previous. This solved the problem for me. I suppose that not working auto-complete is an error which likely to appear when a text box (which was created originally) was changed to a combo.

Answer (score 1):

It does work here (Access 2010, but that shouldn't matter).

I created a table with your field names and sample data, and the combo box with your row source. I added a Appcode of 9900 for easier testing.

[image]

I type `9`, and the item is selected. Or `8302` to select the 3rd item.

You aren't expecting to be able to type e.g. `Ent` to select the `8301` item, are you? This isn't possible, because the column string starts with 8301.

If you want that, the combo box must have 3 columns, with `description` being the second one = the first visible one. `tcoAppCode` would have to be the last column.

Comment: Ok so the question becomes is this an issue with MS Access or something else that's wonky with the application I've been handed :(  I trust you that your solution works because it makes no reason it shouldn't however on my system it's not working :(.

Comment: @whoisearth: So when you start typing `83`, nothing is selected at all? If you want to investigate further, you could add screenshots from design view, of the property sheet for the combobox, tabs Format and Data. Or can you share a copy of your database, where all but that form and the combobox table is removed?