# How to auto fill a combox as the user types?

Tags: vba, ms-access

My combobox called `districtCombo` is bound to a field called `carDistrict`. To help me save time updating the `CarDistrict` field, I want to be able auto fill the combobox as users type.

I thought of using a `select` statement in the `districtCombo_Change` event but I am not getting anything, not even any error message.

Is there a way of getting around this? Or any better suggestions?

```vb
Private Sub districtCombo_Change()
    Dim Task As String
    Task = "SELECT carDistrict FROM tblCars ORDER BY tblCars.districtCombo"
    Me.districtCombo.RowSource = Task
End Sub()
```

My second try is bringing me closer i think. I have abandoned the Change event completely and I constructed a Form_Load event as follows:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()

Me.RecordSource = "tblCars"
districtCombo.ControlSource = "carDistrict"
districtCombo.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
districtCombo.RowSource = "SELECT carDistrict FROM tblCars"

End Sub
```

the problem is, the combobox displays all the values including repeated values and empty fields. There a way of filtering the combobox items so that only one item made up of the same string is displayed?

I think I am getting closer but I have come upon another problem. If the value being typed is not on the list, I am not allowed to add it to the table. Is there a way? Updated code below:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()

Me.RecordSource = "tblCars"
districtCombo.ControlSource = "carDistrict"
districtCombo.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
districtCombo.RowSource = "SELECT distinct carDistrict FROM tblCars WHERE 
carDistrict Is Not null"

End Sub

Private Sub districtCombo_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

 Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblCars")
 rs.AddNew
 rs!carDistrict = NewData
 rs.Update
 End Sub

 Private Sub districtCombo_AfterUpdate()
 Me.Requery
 End Sub
```

I am getting error on the rs.Update part.

And Finally, This is what I was looking for:

```vb
'Set the Limit to list property of the combobox to No

Private Sub Form_Load()
Me.RecordSource = "tblCars"
districtCombo.ControlSource = "carDistrict"
districtCombo.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
districtCombo.RowSource = "SELECT distinct carDistrict FROM tblCars WHERE 
carDistrict Is Not null"
End Sub

Private Sub districtCombo_AfterUpdate()
Me.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Please Pardon me, I don't understand the question: When I want an auto fill, I use a just use combo-box. Try by having the in the control properties, or in the `Form_load` sub, and removing `districtCombo_Change` event handler, I think that should help you get the Auto-fill ability you request.

Comment: @marlan, I have seen this person trying to do something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499766/ms-access-auto-complete-not-working-on-combobox but I cant still get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the combobox has a valid **Row Source** containing all available options, items from the Row Source will automatically appear as the user types in the combobox.

If the list of possible values is **not** stored in a separate table (as you would when following the rules of [database normalisation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics)), then you can populate the combobox with all possible values by specifying the **Row Source** as something like:

```sql
select distinct cardistrict from tblcars where cardistrict is not null
```

You will also need to refresh the row source dataset following the addition of new values.

One way to achieve this is to invoke the `Requery` method of the combobox control within an event handler for the `AfterUpdate` event:

```vb
Private Sub districtCombo_AfterUpdate()
    districtCombo.Requery
End Sub
```

Note that properties such as the form Record Source and combobox Control Source, Row Source, and Row Source Type do **not** need to be populated on the `Load` event of the form, but can be configured in the Form Design.

Comment: But items for the Row Source can be found in the table already. This Items can change from time to time or new items can also be added. Auto fill would help save time entering data or correct misspelling.

Comment: Then have some other event call `districtCombo.Requry` after items are added to tblCars.

Comment: @Lee Mac, this is brilliant, It realy has helped me come closer. However, I have come across another issue. If a user types in a value that does not already exist in the cobobox, It does not accept the value to be added on the table. Please see updated code.

Comment: I think I have got this. By setting the Limit To List property to No. The code now works as expected. No need for the NotInList event. Code Updated! Cheers